# When do I need to specify library source for a function/method in a command?

Tags: python

Sorry for the vague question, but the example bellow will clear up what I am asking.

In the following line of code you need to specify that you are requesting the `read_csv()` function from the library pandas (which is imported as `pd`)

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

However, in the line below, not only is specifying the library not needed it's not working at all.

```
x = df[df["sex"]=="F"].pd.nsmallest(n=1, columns="year")
```

So, when do I need to specify the library and when not?

Is there an occasion that specifying the library in the middle of the line as in the second line above?

How does python know where to get that function/method from? (I am aware that there is a difference between function and method, but my question still stands)

Comment: You need to refer to *defined names*. You define `pd` with an `import` somewhere. And you define `df` with `df = ...`. You don't need to refer to a *library*, you need to refer to something that Python knows what it is.

Answer (score 1):

There are library methods/functions/variables and there are object methods/functions/variables, to access library data you use `library.data` (in your case `pd.read_csv`). To access object data you use `object.data` (in your case `df[df["sex"]=="F"].nsmallest`). You can check that by knowing that `df[df["sex"]=="F"]` is a `pd.DataFrame`, and that the method you're looking for is a method of that object, i.e. `pd.DataFrame.nsmallest`.